# Simple blogger bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, blogger, google-oauth

Hello i'm trying to make a simple bot for blogspot with
insert
publish
delete

but i'm stuck on oauth2Client

What i try :

1° get the token code :

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  'CLIENT_ID ,
  'CLIENTE SECRET ID ',
  'REDIRECT URL '
);


const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'
];

const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
  access_type: 'offline',


  scope: scopes
});
console.log(url);
```

2° paste de url in the browser to login on google

3° then with the tonken code

```
const {tokens} =  oauth2Client.getToken('TOKEN CODE THAT WAS RETURN )
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: tokens, 
  // Optional, provide an expiry_date (milliseconds since the Unix Epoch)
   expiry_date: (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
});


const blogger = google.blogger({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client
});

async function runSample () {
  console.log("running")
  const res = blogger.posts.insert({
    blogId: 'BLOGID',
    requestBody: {
      title: 'Hello from the googleapis npm module!',
      content: 'Visit https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client to learn more!'
    }
  });
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

runSample();
```

the response is

Error: No access, refresh token or API key is set

i already refresh the keys and same old thing

Answer (score 0):

`Tokens` object returned by `oauth2Client.getToken()` contains an access_token and a refresh_token (It also contains expires_in and token_type fields).

So you neeed to write:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: tokens.access_token,
  refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token,
  expiry_date: (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
});
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingresponse